# js api interface with 2 consecutive calls works with postman and fails with curl

Tags: php, curl, postman, php-curl

the problem i cannot post test data is because the ids will be taken once someone tries it out

it is basically a signup. It needs a secret ID plus unused email. Then there is a second step, if both requirements were met in step 1, one can enter full_name and password. The second step is what fails for me in curl, but works using postman, and I have no clue why. Here is the postman export:

https://gist.github.com/Jossnaz/31983240d57038ccb10afa88dd0765ae

here is the naive code I run, I use this curl wrapper:

https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

note: I started with the minimal things I had in postman, but the second call wouldn't work, so I added more things I tried out and left them so you can see what I tried out without high expectation that it would actually make it work

try outs are these:
`$c->get("https://fond.co/public#/id_signup/themotcard.com");`
setting cookies
setting user agent, referer and origin headers

```
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$c = new Curl();
$c->get("https://fond.co/public#/id_signup/themotcard.com");
$c->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
$cookies = $c->getResponseCookies();

$c = new Curl();
$c->setCookies($cookies);
$c->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$c->setHeader('Authorization', 'letmein');
$c->setHeader('X-Anyperk-Client-Id', 'AnyPerk-PublicApp/1/2');
$c->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
$c->post('https://fond.co/api/public/company_staff_signup/signup',
             [
                 "company_domain_name" => "themotcard.com",
                 "staff_identifier"    => "35962466970",
                 "email"               => "tesasdfaftasdxasdfaasdsasdfxabc22321@testabc.com",
             ]);

if ($c->error) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $c->errorCode . ': ' . $c->errorMessage . "\n <br/>" .   var_dump($c->response);
} else {
  echo 'Response:' . "\n";
  var_dump($c->response);
}
sleep(4)
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
$c = new Curl();
$c->setCookies($cookies);
$c->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$c->setHeader('Authorization', 'letmein');
$c->setHeader('X-Anyperk-Client-Id', 'AnyPerk-PublicApp/1/2');
$c->setHeader('Host', 'fond.co');
$c->setHeader('Origin', 'https://fond.co');
$c->setHeader('Referer', 'https://fond.co/public');
$c->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
$c->post('https://fond.co/api/public/company_staff_invitations/staff_details',
         [
             "full_name" => "lukas curl",
             "password" => "test1x2x3x45"
         ]);

if ($c->error) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $c->errorCode . ': ' . $c->errorMessage . "\n";
} else {
  echo 'Response:' . "\n";
  var_dump($c->response);
}
var_dump($c->response);

die('bb');
```

this is the response I get:

```
//step1, the logo indicates a successful submission and creation
  Response: object(stdClass)#2592 (1) { ["logo_url"]=> string(104) "https://d17yvb56124x4l.cloudfront.net/company_informations/customized_logos/8709/original.png?1512057076" } 

//step2
Error: 401: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized object(stdClass)#2599 (1) { ["error"]=> string(12) "Unauthorized" } bb
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue were cookies

this app uses cookies for a session id. php curl nor guzzle or any http client I tried, stored the cookies for the following request. Thus resulting in 401 unauthorized.

I ended up using guzzle btw, I was just trying different http clients and finally ended using guzzle, and that is where I figured out a way how to set the cookies for the second call.

this is my final code (the sleep is set to 3 seconds, probably one can remove the sleep entirely or set it to a lot less. I just found the fix so I will post with 3s sleep)

```
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->post('https://fond.co/api/public/company_staff_signup/signup', [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON =>
                 [
                 "company_domain_name" => "themotcard.com",
                 "staff_identifier"    => "37952992345",
                 "email"               => "tessyyyz3321@testabc.com",
             ]
,
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS => [                         'x-anyperk-client-id' => 'AnyPerk-PublicApp/1/2',
                                                  'authorization' => 'letmein',
                                                  'content-type' => 'application/json']
]);
$cookieJar = new SessionCookieJar('motr_guzzle_sessioncookies', true);

sleep(3);

  $request = new Request('POST', 'https://fond.co/api/public/company_staff_invitations/staff_details',

                         ['x-anyperk-client-id' => 'AnyPerk-PublicApp/1/2',
                          'authorization' => 'letmein',
                          'content-type' => 'application/json'],
  \GuzzleHttp\json_encode([
                              "full_name" => "lukas guzzle",
                              "password" => "test1x2x3x45"
                          ])


                         );
$cookieJar->extractCookies($request, $res);
$request = $cookieJar->withCookieHeader($request);
$res = $client->send($request);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($res);
echo '</pre>';
```